# Is it possible to add a comment to a .swf file?

Tags: comments

I would like a way to add comments to a .swf file without it affecting the code and how the file runs.The reason I need a comment is to prove that this .swf file is owned by me before I give it to others and that I supplied this game to people. So when people say "I downloaded this game off the internet" I can show them the identifier in the source code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unless you have the original file, its not possible, that is the point of a compiler

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just sign your code:

- In Adobe Flash Builder click the File menu, then Export.
- On the Export window expand Flash Builder in the export destination
  list, then click Release Build, then click Next
- On the Export Release Build window select your target platform.
- Click the "Signed packages for each target platform" option
- Click Browse and specify an export location for your application,
  then click Next.
- On the Packaging Settings window, Digital Signature tab, click the
  box next to "Enable digital signing", then click Finish

Comment: yes, but I destroyed the computer I wrote it on and have a new computer with the finished program. Hence the fact that I don't have Adobe Flash Builder on my new computer.

Comment: That's going to be a problem. The point of signing code is that, once it's done, the final binary cannot be modified by any one else without breaking the signature. Any way you find of signing your file now is only going to verify that you were in possession of the file. It won't tell anyone weather you created it.

Comment: Oh thats bad, dam

Comment: maby i can edit a photo.

Comment: WOW JOAO THAT REALLYHELPED...

Comment: I've heard that before.